# Ad blocker blocks my json file on my ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datatable, adblock

I use DataTable in my rails app and return from the server Json file in the name of the model the model name is have the word AD in it so the ad blocker blocks me.
there is a way to solve this without rename the name of the model?

Comment: Beyond adding your specific URL/file name to a whitelist for the specific adblocker, I'm going to say probably not possible. If the was, the ad companies would probably use it.